# How to use fill property with unequal number of factors?

Tags: r, ggvis

I have this dataset

```
structure(list(collegeAbb = c("Agriculture", "Agriculture", "Agriculture", 
"Art", "Art", "Art", "Business", "Business", "Business", "Coast", 
"Coast", "Coast", "Engineering", "Engineering", "Engineering", 
"Human Science", "Human Science", "Human Science", "Humanities", 
"Humanities", "Humanities", "Law", "MassComm", "MassComm", "MassComm", 
"Music", "Music", "Music", "Not provided", "Not provided", "Not provided", 
"Science", "Science", "Science", "Veterinary", "Veterinary", 
"Veterinary"), degreeLevel = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L
), .Label = c("Bachelor", "Master", "PhD"), class = "factor"), 
    count = c(775, 151, 83, 439, 93, 2, 2309, 857, 37, 45, 49, 
    22, 2039, 294, 154, 1845, 876, 116, 3021, 339, 144, 3, 659, 
    60, 12, 173, 117, 52, 8, 3, 5, 1346, 176, 167, 5, 9, 201)), .Names = c("collegeAbb", 
"degreeLevel", "count"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -37L))
```

And I am trying to map the variable `degreeLevel` to the fill attribute this way:

```
dd %>%
ggvis(x=~collegeAbb, y=~count) %>%
  layer_bars( fill:= ~ factor(degreeLevel))
```

However, because not all the variables in `collegeAbb`, when I set `fill:=~factor(degreeLevel)` I get an error message:

```
Warning message:
In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
```

How can I tell ggvis to consider the values for missing factor values to zero?

Comment: The only place in R that I know uses `:=` is data.table's version of "[". Is it really the case that whatever unnamed package that has a function named `ggvis` in it also uses `:=` to assign formula objects?

Comment: @42- Thansk,that's the mistake, but ggvis actually uses `:=` to map values to layers (for instance `fill:="#fff"`)

Comment: So we should close this as a typo?

Comment: @42- In my case it's a typo but there is a difference between `:=` and `=` in ggvis, maybe others my benefit from and answer...but feel free to close if you believe it's not very useful

Comment: And feel free to post an answer with an explanation. In this case I'm really not in a postition to judge since I'm not an experienced ggvis user, and it appears there are aspects of its internal and idiosyncratic syntax that would surprise me.